# Ask someone in a sincere to do something

Tags: vocabulary

Which one of following is used in british english:
1-I beg you talk with my boss
2-I implore you talking with my boss

Comment: Neither. It's *"Would you **please** speak to my boss?"*

Comment: If you must use _beg_, it's _I beg you to talk with my boss_. (NB _British English_ takes capital letters.)

Answer (score 1):

Using "beg" or "implore" sounds hyperbolic and silly.  Both "beg" and "implore" invoke a kind of desperation that doesn't fit with the business context of "talk to my boss".  You might beg someone to spare your life, or implore your wife not to leave you. These are words that are used in situations of high emotion.

You could say "Please talk to my boss" or with a bit more rhetoric: "Would you please talk to my boss?"

If you must use words like "beg", then "I beg you to talk to my boss" or "I implore you to talk..."  There is not much difference.